# Github project filter

Tags: gratis, linux, search, github

I want to monitor what Github projects had recent activity – but want to limit that to topics I'm interested in. Say, I want to see what Android apps are currently active – but I'm not interested in libraries, games, SDKs (i.e. most development-related stuff). Sure I can run a query like `android NOT game NOT sdk` etc. – but the length of search terms is limited (e.g. to a maximum of 5 NOTs). So at best, this example would have me skimming 30+ pages per day – with more than 50% of the results still in the development sector.

I'm looking for a tool/plugin/script to make that easier. This can be a browser plugin (for Firefox), a shell script or GUI tool (Linux), or something else along those lines which I'm not aware of. Requirements:

- must be usable on Linux (no Wine/VMWare or other emulator)
- must allow to filter out projects by terms appearing in project name and short description
- must allow for larger filter sets
- should be easy to deal with
- results can be shown in browser, come out as RSS, or be stored as e.g. CSV
- results must include a link to the project, and carry its name. Strongly wanted: also the short description, number of stars. Really nice-to-have: number of releases.
- must allow to sort at least by "latest update"
- should be gratis, preferably open-source

Comment: not at all what you're looking for here, but someone interested in this *might* also be interested in http://gource.io/

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Looks cool, but doesn't match: according to the description on that page, it works on *local repositories* (and their logs). I cannot mirror the entire Github site for that – apart from the fact it would in no way provide what I need :) Interesting, though.